# dual-boot, windows 10 can see Ubuntu ext4 partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10 by dividing my `D:\` drive into two `ext4` partition for `/` and `/home`, and a swap area. But on my Windows OS, I can still see the `D:\` drive! which shouldn't happen as I understood (since windows doesn't support `ext4`).
So, is there something wrong with my installation, and is it OK to open this drive from Windows.
The reason I'm asking this, is because I have already tried and opened this drive and it caused a booting failure and got me stuck with grub rescue promote with an error message `attempt to read or write outside of partition` and eventually, I had to reinstall Ubuntu again. but I also installed [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com) in the same session, so I'm not sure which one caused the boot failure.
Note that I was able to see the drive before installing ext2fsd , and still can after uninstalling it.

**EDIT :** both OS's are on the same physical drive. `D:/` is a partition.

The screenshot of "Disks" from comments:

[image]

Comment: @user68186 https://imgur.com/a/IJ8hEKX

Comment: I guarantee you that `ext2fsd` corrupted your Ubuntu file system. An `fsck` might have fixed it without a reinstall. If after rebooting, you can still see the ext4 filesystem from Windows, you may have another one of these nasty drivers installed.

Comment: ext2fsd in Windows has corrupted at least half a dozen innocent ext4 filesystems. Just Say No to ext2fsd.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, you're right. it's `ext2fsd` that messed up my system. The `D`  drive finally disappeared after 3 to 4 re-boots.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Regarding your answer, I can't tell if it would work, because I've already re-installed Ubuntu over my previous installation, which allowed me to boot successfully. Other than that, the `D` drive issue was solved after uninstalling `ext2fsd` and couple of re-boots. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guarantee you that Windows driver `ext2fsd` corrupted your Ubuntu file system. Uninstall it asap.

**Let's see if we can recover your Ubuntu file system...**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`